# How can I use REST API authentication in Mendix?

Tags: rest, authentication, bonita, mendix

I have designed an API REST service (with Bonita) to which I can perfectly connect with Postman, with the following parameters:

[image]

By the way, the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option that is selected comes from the `Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header that is not displayed in my screenshot. The [official Bonita specification](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.10/rest-api-authentication#toc0) states that this header is needed and I always get a `200-OK` status code as an answer.

How can I specify an equivalent request with the body part in a Mendix `Call REST service` in a microflow? Here is what I have so far:

[image]
[image]

I guess the body part should be specified in the `Request` tab, but I just don't know how to do it properly. I always get the following error message for my connector, which means that, whatever I specify, the username is not taken into account:

`An error has occurred while handling the request. [User 'Anonymous_69a378ed-bb56-4183-ae71-c9ead783db1f' with session id '5fefb6ad-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXb34f' and roles 'Administrator']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that the proxy setting was the actual problem. It was set at the project scope and simply clicking on `No proxy` in the `General` tab did the trick! (both services are hosted on my local machine so far)

I just had to fill in the dedicated `Authentication` field in the `HTTP Headers` tab then, with the correct credentials, to eventually log in my Bonita service.